# Can a state lattice planner be used purely as a local planner?

Tags: mobile-robot, motion-planning, navigation, planning

I've been reading a bit about state lattice motion planning recently. The question I would like to ask is if a lattice-based motion planning system can be used purely as a local planner without a lattice-based global planned path for mobile robots.

In other words, given I have a global plan as a sequence of waypoints to follow, can I use a lattice-based local planner for obstacle avoidance?

Comment: Could you give an example of a lattice based local planner?

Comment: I am still looking for a lattice based local planner. Some of the literature in the area, including [Differentially Constrained mobile robot motion planning in state lattices](https://rpal.cs.cornell.edu/docs/PivEtal_JFR_2009.pdf) and [State Space Sampling of Feasible Motions for high-performance mobile robot navigation](https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub4/howard_thomas_2008_1/howard_thomas_2008_1.pdf) use lattices for motion replanning. But my understanding is that they already have a lattice-based global plan, and they then conduct dynamic replanning in the presence of obstacles

Comment: lattices discretize a continuos space. This allows a graph-theoretical approach to planning, which can offer global optimality guarantees. Local planners function like numerical optimisation methods. These work in continuos space and they find the next local minima, in the simplest case, closest to the initial solution. Based on this assumption, I cannot give you an example for a lattice space local planner.